# Why does measuring a GHZ state in the computational basis destroy the entanglement?

Tags: measurement, ghz-state

Measuring in a basis other than the computational (Z) basis will generally destroy any entanglement present in the GHZ state, as the entanglement is defined with respect to specific basis states. Why?

(FYI, if I measure GHZ in z state, it will give me a probability consisting of results of 111 and 000 only which is correct. But if I measure it different basis such as X, I will get also probability results of 010, 100, etc. When I do the same in bell state, it gave me perfect probability results, in all basis measurements)

Comment: Entanglement is not defined with respect to a specific basis. Read more [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267293). Try writing the Bell state and GHZ state in the Hadamard basis. That should improve your understanding of why this happens.

Comment: Understood. But is there any other basis other than computational basis (for GHZ of course ) I can measure with which will give me results like computational basis aka z basis measurement? If the answer is yes, how can I find it, is there any shortcut?

Comment: what do you mean with "why"? Are you asking how to show this mathematically?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Comment: I think the question is ill-posed. Measuring in any product basis will "destroy the entanglement" in the sense that the post-measurement state is a product state. What are you actually asking? I think it is about correlated measurement outcomes which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: I am sorry. My major is not in Physics and kinda new to this. Actually u r right, it's the correlated measurement outcomes result.

Answer (score 2):

The two-qubit GHZ state (Bell state) case is special: any measurement in a basis
$$
\cos\theta X+\sin\theta Z
$$
will return perfectly correlated results between the two parties.

In the case of a larger GHZ state, measuring one qubit in the Z is the only single-qubit measurement that returns a fully separable state of the other qubits (and hence has completely predictable outcomes when you measure in the corresponding bases, which happen to all be the $Z$ basis). Any other measurement that you make will return an entangled state, which means there's at least two different possible outcomes when you make single-qubit measurements.